# Windows: VSCode Python 3 virtualenv not working when trying to install package

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm using Python 3.10.4. I'm trying to work on a Django project, but when I create a Virtualenv then installing the package is not working.

```
PS C:\Users\schad\Desktop\importExport> & c:/Users/schad/Desktop/importExport/env/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(env) PS C:\Users\schad\Desktop\importExport> pip install django-import-export
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\schad\Desktop\env\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\schad\Desktop\importExport\env\Scripts\pip.exe" install django-import-export': The system cannot find the file specified.

(env) PS C:\Users\schad\Desktop\importExport> pip install mysqlclient
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\schad\Desktop\env\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\schad\Desktop\importExport\env\Scripts\pip.exe" install mysqlclient': The system cannot find the file specified.

(env) PS C:\Users\schad\Desktop\importExport>
```

[image: project]

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, the terminal trying to using

`C:\Users\schad\Desktop\env\Scripts\python.exe`

but it should be

`C:\Users\schad\Desktop\importExport\env\Scripts\pip.exe`,

Could you try to switch the python interpreter to another one? And please check whether you have configured something in your settings.json file although this should be stored in the storage under `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User` folder.

You can try to switch to another python interpreter and then switch back, if it still does not work you can delete `state.vscdb` under `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage` folder.